# Searching with multiple values in one column of Mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a database `demo` with a table named `country`.

Table contains two columns `countryID` and `countryName`

I want to search multiple values in column `countryName` to get `countryID`

The one way to do this is by using `AND` operator but in that case the number of values must be same for all the cases.

i.e

```
select countryID from country where countryName = "USA" AND countryName = "INDIA"
```

So, I am looking for the solution which cloud help me to search **N** number of values in column `countryName` to get `countryID`

Comment: Geuss you are looking to OR instead off AND. `SELECT countryID from country where countryName = "USA" OR countryName = "INDIA" ` makes more sense.

Comment: what do you mean with "the number of values must be same for all the cases" ?

Comment: The `WHERE` clause works on records. One record cannot have the country 'USA' **AND**  'INDIA'  at the same time. It can be 'USA' **OR**  'INDIA'. So if you are looking for all records matching one of the given countries, use `OR` or `IN`.

Comment: On a sidenote: you should use standard-compliant quotes for strings, which are single qoutes (e.g. `'USA'`).

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PHP, unless OP asked SO users to write the code for him. In the question body I only see SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT countryID FROM country WHERE countryName IN ("value1", "value2", "value3")
```

As many values as you like.

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` function is the shorthand for the operator `OR` which takes multiple arguments as values in `WHERE` clause of SQL query.

For example
If we have 6 values to query for in a single column, then with `OR` operator it could be:

```
SELECT countryID FROM country WHERE countryName = "USA" OR countryName = "India" OR countryName = "Pakistan" OR countryName = "Iran" OR countryName = "Afghanistan" OR countryName = "Turkey";
```

With `IN` it could be:

```
SELECT countryID FROM country WHERE countryName IN ("USA", "India", "Pakistan", "Iran", "Afghanistan", "Turkey");
```

You can pass as many values you want to `IN` function.